# Border top still displayed

Tags: html, css, border

When I re-size the browser, the border-top is displayed even I set the border-top to none or 0. Also, I adjusted the color to transparent but still the border-top is displayed. How to remove the border-top?

Here's the link http://bit.ly/1LKU7eC

CSS:

```
.accordionfaq-toggle{ cursor: pointer; font-size: 18px; border-radius: 3px; padding: 19px 19px 19px 60px; -80px 0 10px 0; font-weight: bold; }
.arrow:before{ content: '\f054'; font-family: FontAwesome; display: inline-block; padding-right: 30px; vertical-align: middle; color: #d31716; margin-left: -40px; }
.accordionfaq-toggle:active{ border-bottom: none; }
.accordionfaq-content{ display: none; border-radius: 3px; border-right: 1px solid #CCC; border-left: 1px solid #CCC; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC; box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); background: #FFF; margin: -87px 0 19px 0; padding: 4em 3em 3em 4em;
```

Comment: border top for which element?

Comment: Border-top of what??!

Comment: Please, explain more. Post the screenshot of your problem.

Comment: BORDER-TOP OF WHAT????!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not actually a `border` but a `box-shadow`

Changing the `.accordionfaq-content` media query for `(max-width: 640px)` like this will fix it

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px)
.accordionfaq-content {
    padding: 4em 1em 3em 1em;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

its box shadow so Please update below css property in "box-shadow"  for the unwanted top shadow.

```
.accordionfaq-content{box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
```